# Laravel rest api not working properly

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-5.1

I've build the backend on Laravel and calling the api's on android device and desktop browser.

The problem is the login api works fine and returns user data based on api-token. But 2 out 10 times it fails.

It returns

```
Method Not Found error
```

I can't understand what the problem is and where to look for..

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: check method post or get or other

Comment: @Kool-Mind - it is post

Comment: I mean what's in route? and check form's method i.e calling api method. this error comes for that only